# How to fix a bug in Event Registration: Data Does not change in checkout after using go back button?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, error

I created an online registration form in CiviCRM installed in WordPress. Everything functions well, except if Im not logged in and use the go back button and change some data in most of the time the data is not changed in the checkout screen.
How can i fix that? How can i debug it? Is there a way to see which code is executed if onClick is called? Im still searching for the code who is executed if someone uses the go back button and or the continue button.

Here a link to the form, i deactivated all custom javascript code for now.
Otherwise its mainly pure CiviCrm code.

https://divinya.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=2

Just tested it on a plain Wordpress installation, same bug is there:
https://centerforevolutionaryconsciousness.org/civi2/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&id=1&reset=1

I tested it now also on Drupal with same configuration and this bug is not there, so it seems to be related to Drupal on Wordpress.

Comment: i pasted a link in https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress

Comment: Are these CiviCRM instances on the same server?

Comment: they are on two different servers, but both with Siteground hosting.